# Why is my code returning the wrong index number?

Tags: ruby, indexing

Need help with this homework problem. How do I write a function, nearest_larger(arr, i) which takes an array and an index. The function should return another index. The conditions are below. Thanks.

```
This should satisfy:

(a) `arr[i] < arr[j]`, AND
(b) there is no `j2` closer to `i` than `j` where `arr[i] < arr[j]`.
```

> In case of ties (see example beow), choose the earliest (left-most) of the two indices. If no number in `arr` is largr than `arr[i]`, return `nil`.
>
> example:
>
> nearest_larger([2,3,4,8], 2).should == 3
>      end

My code is:

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)

  greater_nums = []

  arr.each {|element| greater_nums << element if element>idx}

    sorted_greater_nums= greater_nums.sort

    nearest_larger = sorted_greater_nums[0]

    arr.index(nearest_larger)

end
```

THANKS a lot guys. See post below for solution

Comment: It'd be good for you to learn how to format your questions. As you write them you can use the "?" button above the entry text box to bring up help for all aspects of formatting the content.

Comment: Can you post what you are testing your code against and what do you get in return?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it "without the left/right way"? Are you aware this approach is significantly less efficient? (I'm not saying that it necessarily really matters—just curious why this would be your preference and also whether or not you're at least *aware* of the inefficiency.)

Comment: Also, as I pointed out in another comment, your sorting approach will not return correct results for unsorted arrays. Try: `nearest_larger([1, 2, 0], 2)`

Comment: I don't get the question.  Can someone explain what this question is asking? A makes sense.  B not so much.  At first I thought it was trying to find the nearest number larger than idx in the array, but that's not true given the second rspec test where 2 should yield 1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least two mistakes here.

First, your code seems to assume the array is sorted. (Otherwise why would taking the least of `greater_nums` give you the closest index?) But from your requirements (choose the left-most index in case of a tie), that is clearly not guaranteed.

More importantly, in your `each` loop you're comparing `element` to `idx` (the **index** passed in) rather than `arr[idx]`.

I think what you really want to do is something like this:

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  value = arr[idx]

  # Ensure idx is actually valid.
  return nil if idx < 0 || idx >= arr.length

  left, right = [idx - 1, idx + 1]
  while (left >= 0 || right < arr.length)
    # Always check left first, per the requirement.
    return left if left >= 0 && arr[left] > value
    return right if right < arr.length && arr[right] > value

    # Incrementally move farther and farther left/right from the specified index
    # looking for a larger value.
    left, right = [left - 1, right + 1]
  end

  # This will return nil if no values were larger than arr[idx].
end
```

Comment: This will fail for small arrays of size: 0, 1 and 2. Also if index is 0 and array.length -1!

Comment: @mbj: It would originally only have failed if `idx` was outside of the array entirely. I've added a check for that case. You're wrong about the other scenarios, though (load up `irb` and try it).

Comment: def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  greater_nums = []
  arr.each {|element| greater_nums << element if element>arr[idx]}
    sorted_greater_nums= greater_nums.sort
    nearest_larger = sorted_greater_nums[0]
    
    answer =arr.index(nearest_larger)
    puts answer
    
end

Comment: @user2391263: That's not going to work if the array isn't sorted. Try it on this input: `nearest_larger([1, 2, 0], 2)`. It will output `0` even though the element at index 1 is still larger, and closer.

Comment: Hey right. I misunderstood the question :(. for some reason i assumed it wanted the number closest to it. Thanks a lot for ur input

Comment: @DanTao - why the brackets around the right-hand side of the parallel assignments?  Just curious.

Comment: @pjs: Just habit. In rare cases when I've written methods that return, e.g., two values, I've found it clearer to add the brackets as it clarifies that what's actually being returned is an array. But as far as I know there's no difference between including or omitting them.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you explain why we must use the || instead of && in "while (left >= 0 || right < arr.length)"? I know that || is the correct answer to get the output in ruby otherwise everything ends up being nil. I am trying to understand why because in my mind, shouldn't we require that both left>=0 AND right<arr.length always be true?? Thanks

Comment: @JamieS: The reason for using `||` is that you're probably going to reach outside the array on one side sooner than the other, unless you start in the exact middle (which is impossible if the array has an even number of elements). So you want to keep trying as long as there's still an index to check on *either* side, not on *both* sides. Notice that inside the loop the code still checks each index individually to make sure it's valid.

Comment: Thank you!! I forgot about that aspect (going to reach outside the array on one side sooner than the other)! Now I understand!!